# Replacing <a> tag with <b> tag using PHP

Tags: php, html

OK, I have a section of code with things like:
    `<a title="title" href="http://example.com">Text</a>`

I need to reformat these somehow so that they become:
    `<b>Text</b>`

There are at least 24 links being changed, and they all have different titles and hrefs. Thanks in advance, Austin.

Comment: HTML or XHTML? If XHTML you can do it simply with the SimpleXML library...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although not optimal, you can do this with regular expressions:

```
$string = '<a title="title" href="http://example.com">Text</a>';

$string = preg_replace("/<a\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/a>/is", "<b>$2</b>", $string);

echo($string);
```

This essentially says, look for a part of the string that has the form `<a*>{TEXT}</a>`, copy the `{TEXT}`, and replace that whole matched string with `<b>{TEXT}</b>`.

Comment: Did you want some kind of whitespace after the opening `a` in the tag to avoid changing tags that start with `a`?

Comment: You need to escape the `/` in `</a>` or use a different delimiter. That is, either `"/<a(.+?)>(.+?)<\\/a>/is"` or `"#<a(.+?)>(.+?)</a>#is"` (I would use the second)

Comment: I figured I forgot something, fixed for both.

Comment: A single backslash won't cut it. Remember that there's two levels of backslash interpretation going on here -- the quotes in PHP and in the regex engine. You need two backslashes or the other delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$link = '<a title="title" href="http://example.com">Text</a>';
echo $formatted = "<b>".strip_tags($link)."</b>";
```

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) link out as well, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: And if the HTML happened to be `<a href="#">One link</a> some text <a href="#">Another link</a>`, wouldn't that break here?  The OP didn't say the links were in separate strings, and it'd be quite odd if they were.

Comment: True, but since he didn't really specify how he would be getting the links, or if they would be in and amongst other HTML, that should work fine for what he asked. But I do see your point, in which case `shmeeps` answer would be the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

You want to read about [Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/) because you will need them sooner or later anyway. If you do not mind about the content of the href property, then you can use:

```
s/<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>([^<]+)<\/a>/<b>\1<\/b>/
```

The part between the first // searches for the opening tag (either <a> alone or with some parameters, in this case a white space \s is required to avoid matching <abbrev> e.g. as well), some text which will stored by the brackets, and the closing tag. The part between the second // is the replacement part where \1 denotes the text matched by the brackets in the first part.

See also PHP’s [preg_replace](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function. The final expression would then look like this (tested):

```
preg_replace('/<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>([^<]+)<\/a>/i', '<b>\\1</b>', '<a href="blabla">Text</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace a tag by another and matching / replacing attributes names at the same time :

```
$string = '<img src="https://example.com/img.png" alt="Alternative"/>';
$string = preg_replace('/<img src="(.+?)" alt="(.+?)"\\/>/is','<amp-img src="$1" alt="$2"></amp-img>',$string);
//$string is now '<amp-img src="https://example.com/img.png" alt="Alternative"></amp-img>'
```

Comment: <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51QjVunNb+L.jpg" alt="Test

Is there any solution for finding this image using a regex src tag is complete, but the image alt tag is missing double quote and greater than at the end?